# Title in AppBar grows too large

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

On some views I show the name of a selected item as the title of the `AppBar`. But when the name is very long, the `VBox`containing the title label grows to the prefWidth of the label. You can see the result on the first picture. 
As a workaround I add a styleClass to the appBar, which sets the maxWidth for the label.

```
   view.setOnShown(e -> getAppBar().getStyleClass().add("myStyleClass"));
```

Although it's working, it's bad practice to set the maxWidth like that, because it can't be adjusted to different screen sizes.

How can I achieve the result on the second picture, and make the title's width adapt to different screen sizes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty workaround to set the max width of the label based on the scene dimensions could be, on a View subclass:

```
@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setTitleText("Very very very long title");
    ((Label) appBar.getTitle()).maxWidthProperty().bind(appBar.getScene().widthProperty().subtract(100));       
}
```

where the amount to subtract will depend on the number of buttons (nav icon, action icons or menu button) you have in that view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about as well. Certainly a better solution, though I'm not sure if I like the idea of using fixed values, as you would still have to know the size of your additional items.

Comment: This should be fixed with the [release](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-mobile-2-2-0-released/) of the new Charm 2.2.0 version. Can you check?